# Is this pointwise convergence sequence also uniform convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, integration, convergence-divergence

$f_{n}$ and $f$ are continuous functions and  $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise. Which of the following are correct?

1. $\int _{0}^{x}F_{n}\left( t\right) dt\rightarrow\int _{0}^{x}F\left( t\right) dt$
2. $\int _{0}^{x}f_{n}\left( t\right) dt\rightarrow\int _{0}^{x}f\left( t\right) dt$
3. $F_{n}'\left( x\right) \rightarrow f\left( x\right)$

where $F_{n}\left( x\right) =\int f_{n}\left( x\right) dx$ and $F\left( x\right) =\int f\left( x\right) dx$

I think the key to this problem is to deduce whether  $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly or not. I got stucked in how to prove that.

Any counter-examples for 1 and 2？

Comment: You need to precise the $F_n$'s by setting $F_n(x):=\int_{x_0}^xf_n$. The formula $\int f_n$ is only defined up to a constant.

Comment: Your $t(x)$ should be $f(x)$, and then $3$ is trivially true.

Comment: $f_n\not{\rightarrow}f$. uniformly.

Comment: @user57 The assumption is: $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise. And $3$ does not mention uniform convergence.

Comment: No, sorry, I was addressing OP's last sentence.

Comment: @julien How to prove fn is uniformed to f, how to use the definition  of uniformed coverage？

Comment: @user57 Oh, I see... Sorry.

Comment: @frame99 If you only assume pointwise convergence and continuity, and nothing else, you will never prove uniform convergence...Example: $f_n(x):=\frac{x}{n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ converges pointwise to $0$, but not uniformly.

Comment: @frame99 if you have additionally $f_n$ is non decreasing and original interval is compact, then convergence uniform. See Dini's Theorem.

Comment: @user57 Thanks. Rudin’s book?

Comment: yes, It's there as well. 7.13.